# Which to use: « le fait que » or « que »

Tags: grammaire

> [original] : Ce n'est pas tant le sort de votre collègue qui devrait vous inquiéter, mais plutôt **que** la patronne vous **ait** dans le collimateur.
>
> [my version] : Ce n'est pas tant le sort de votre collègue qui devrait vous inquiéter, mais plutôt **le fait que** la patronne vous **a** dans le collimateur.

---

In the original sentence, the part after the « que » serves as the subject:

> **Que** la patronne vous **ait** dans le collimateur devrait vous inquiéter.

So shouldn’t « le fait » be placed before « que »:

> **Le fait que** la patronne vous **a** dans le collimateur devrait vous inquiéter.

---

Also, I’m not sure why the subjunctive is used in the original sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both *que* and *le fait que* are usable here.

With *que*, the subjunctive is used because the reported fact is left open to interpretation.

If you add *le fait*, you are stating it is a fact so the indicative is also appropriate.

Reference about the subjunctive/indicative usage with *le fait que*:

[Dire ou ne pas dire, Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/mary-laure-b-france).

Comment: Merci. Which version would you use yourself? Also, I suppose that the following construction is not allowed (with the "que" clause placed at the top)? If this clause is placed at the top, is the use of "le fait que" required? (x) :  "Que la patronne vous ait dans le collimateur devrait vous inquiéter." nor (x) : "Que la patronne vous a dans le collimateur devrait vous inquiéter."

Comment: Using "le fait" is more wordy. I would use it only to emphasize that I'm stating an established fact.

Comment: *Le fait que* is never mandatory. *Que la patronne vous ait dans le collimateur devrait…* is fine, *Que la patronne vous a dans le collimateur…* is not. *Le fait que la patronne vous a dans le collimateur…* is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The subjunctive has to be used in both cases. (Le fait) que la patronne vous ait dans le collimateur devrait vous inquiéter.

Raison:

1- La patronne vous a dans le collimateur. C'est une information, un constat : indicatif

2- Reprise (au subjonctif) de cette information pour en faire un commentaire, pour en dire autre chose:'cela devrait vous inquiéter'.

Dans l'exemple donné, l'information nouvelle est 'cela devrait vous inquiéter'.

Avec une définition fausse de la vraie nature du subjonctif (grammaires traditionnelles) on le fait disparaître progressivement dans les énoncés qui semblent faire exception!

Une règle de grammaire comprenant des exceptions est une règle fausse. Cela signifie que la vraie règle n'a pas encore été mise à jour ou n'a pas encore atteint le public. Je parle ici de grammaire, pas d'orthographe.

Comment: Sans « le fait que » c'est un hypothèse et seul le subjonctif est possible. Mais avec « le fait que », subjonctif et indicatif sont possible, l'information peut être annoncée (indicatif) ou admise (subjonctif).